# prevent popover from creating scroll in parent (in pure css)

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, overflow

I would like to create a simple popover that displays in place (think about a combobox list below a button). The popover should display over existing elements, i.e. not pre allocate space.

There are many examples using `position: relative -> overflow: hidden -> position: absolute' hierarchy and the work until the popover flows off the bottom of the container, in which case its size affect the parent container and creates a scroll.

Here is a [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/meiriko/pen/EXXeNg?editors=1100). What I'm trying to get is to have no scroll on the rightmost column.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>no overflow</h2>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>basic overflow</h2>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>popover without overflow</h2>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
    <div class="overlay">
      popover should be vislble below
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="absolute short">
          z
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>popover with overflow</h2>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
    <div class="overlay">
      popover should be vislble below
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="absolute">
          z
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tall">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the scss file:

```
html, body {
  height: 95%;

}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  .column {
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: auto;
    .tall {
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .overlay {
      position: relative;
      .overflow {
        background: #F00;
        overflow: hidden;
        .absolute {
          opacity: 0.5;
          width: 100%;
          height: 600px;
          position: absolute;
          background: #FF0;
          &.short {
            height: 200px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do this? If so, share your code.

Comment: If the popover is larger than the container, why don't you want to create a scroll? otherwise, some part of it would be hidden.

Comment: usign position:absolute and negative top values wont affect the parent container

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I posted before I completed the code. Attached is the code and a link

Comment: The reason I don't want a scroll is that I want to be able to later query the popover and see if it is off screen and do js manipulations

Answer (score 1):

I think (if I'm clear about the question) that this issue can be pretty easily resolved by simply substituting the `height` of your tall class with `min-height` and `max-height` If you set the min-height equal to the short height then the popover shouldn't overflow.

I made my own [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRRBqX?editors=1100) do demonstrate (i adjusted the popover to 100 in height and set the min-height also to 100 for demo) . The code is the same as the code you posted except for the height in the `.short` class and min-/max-heights in the `.tall` class. I added `overflow:hidden;` to the short class in the event that the the height of the content in the popover being greater than the height assigned.

I have commented out the columns with no popovers but feel free to comment them in.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx @Rachel, do you refer to the left or right column? The right column still adds a scrollbar while the right one truncates the popover before it reaches the column end. I tend to use flex and responsive design and prefer to avoid physical measures.

Comment: the left one is the one i adjusted - the short one. you can adjust as you see fit. I left the right one unaltered for comparative purposes. you can adjust the left one to max-height:either (bigger) or auto but you should know how big the popover is gonna be

Comment: Thx again, had a look. It works nicely and as you pointed out, I need to know the size in advance. I will probably continue in the search for a flow based (flex) solution

Comment: Glad I could help :)